# aux: command not found when using "ps aux" in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm questioning my sanity at the moment. On MacOS if I try to execute this script for example:

```
#!/bin/bash
OUTPUT=ps aux |grep "somename"
echo $OUTPUT
```

Executing resolves to:

```
./test.sh: line 2: aux: command not found
```

In Terminal it works just fine:

```
% ps aux | grep "somename"
root    29597   0.0  0.1   11264    2224  0  S+   18:11      0:00.00 grep somename
```

I obviously don't want to execute a command called `aux`, but the argument of `ps`. Did I forget some brackets or quotations or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are assigning the value "ps" to the variable `OUTPUT` and execute `aux |grep "somename"`.

If you want to assign the output of `ps aux |grep "somename"` to your variable, you need to tell `bash` to do so:

`OUTPUT=$(ps aux |grep "somename")`

Comment: Ah okay completely forgot that. Thank you!